# Kubernetes (OpenShift)  kubectl (oc - OpenShift CLI) `patch` return the error: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type map[string]interface {}

Tags: go, kubernetes, yaml, openshift, kubectl

I try to `patch` a `service` (add port declaration):

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: istio-ingressgateway
  namespace: istio-system
  labels:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    istio: ingressgateway
    release: istio
spec:
  ports:
    - name: status-port
      protocol: TCP
      port: 15021
      targetPort: 15021
      nodePort: 30805
    - name: http2
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 32130
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 8443
      nodePort: 30720
    - name: tls
      protocol: TCP
      port: 15443
      targetPort: 15443
      nodePort: 31202
  selector:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    istio: ingressgateway
  clusterIP: 172.30.62.239
  type: LoadBalancer
  sessionAffinity: None
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

using `kubectl` or `oc` `patch`-command

```
kubectl patch service istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system --patch - <<EOF
spec:
  ports:
    - name: gw
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3080
      targetPort: 3080
      nodePort: 31230
EOF
```

, but get an error

```
Error from server (BadRequest): json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type map[string]interface {}
```

under the hood, `k8s/openshift` use `GoLang` to parse `yaml`  I tried to find same solutions in `go` - failed...

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use `json` to `patch`

```
oc patch service/simple-server -p \
'{ "spec": { "ports": [ { "name": "gw", "protocol": "TCP", "port": 1234,"targetPort": 1234 } ] } }'
```